# Will IAR complier optimization causing trouble on code running?

Tags: embedded, firmware, iar, stm8

the code is using IAR High Level optimization with STM8L151G3, and I observed some problems on the production unit.

In each loop, the code will execute the code below:

```
__IO uint8_t ColorSwapFlag = 0;

// some other codes.....

if(ColorSwapFlag == 0){
   ColorSwapFlag = 1;
}else{
   ColorSwapFlag = 0;
}
```

the device will display different color depending the value of

```
ColorSwapFlag
```

One of the conditions to execute the code is by the detecting the falling and rising edge of a external interrupt.

I used two units to connect with each of them together in a way that they share the same external interrupt trigger together (to achieve some kind of synchronization of the color swap).

upon powered up both the 2 units syncs just fine, but after only less than a minute one of the unit cannot swap at all, but observing the behavior it seems like the code above failed to work (ColorSwapFlag is stucked at 1 or 0 and never changed). Meanwhile the device is continute to work but only unable to swap colors.

The interesting thing is, after several repeat experiments out of two units, only one particular unit is having this trouble, the other one is not having this problem whatsoever. I probed the signal on the external interrupt trigger and nothing was out of the ordinary.

If the problematic unit runs on it's own (Yes, the unit also have sources to trigger the external interrupt by itself), it will not have this issue.

Right now it is hard to determine whether this is a hardware problem or software optimization problem, or just something went wrong in the production run?

Comment: Optimisers consider your code holistically, but you have shown a tiny eluded  fragment.  It is impossible to tell.  Why is `ColorSwapFlag` declared `_IO` when it is not I/O?  It may be an alias for `volatile`, but semantically you should probably use `volatile` directly.  Also you have made the toggle unnecessarily complex.  Consider `ColorSwapFlag = !ColorSwapFlag` - although you would hope perhaps that the optimiser might do that in any case, but willfully inefficient code gives the optimiser a lot of scope for changing your code.  I'd also suggest using `bool` rather than `uint8_t` here.

Comment: @Clifford does this mean it's better not to use optimizer if possible?

Comment: Cond changing behaviour when optimised is normally a sign of use of undefined behaviour, so you should not ignore it, the code is flawed regardless.  Alternatively it may be a timing issue, with some race condition with a different outcome in the optimised cide.  That said, if the code fits and meets performance requirements, use of aggressive optimisation for its own sake serves no purpose.  That said, under maintenance changes may occur that need optimisation, and your code may then break in ways unrelated to the change.

Comment: Very likely a race condition bug indeed. In case this variable is set by an interrupt then maybe consider moving the toggling into the interrupt too. Or if that's not an option, use a separate variable _not_ shared with the ISR to keep track of the state.

Comment: @Lundin, actually my wording is not very precise there, `ColorSwapFlag` is not inside the Interrupt Handler Code, it was another toggling variable that's inside the Interrupt Handler, and this `ColorSwapFlag` code in the main while loop will check the toggling variable to execute relevant codes in the main loop. As far as I concerned this toggling variable are not having problems since the other parts of the code that in the same execution order with `ColorSwapFlag` works. (by observate the behavior)

Comment: Then why is it declared as `__IO`? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The code for handling `ColorSwapFlag` looks fine to me. I cannot think of any problem with compiler optimizations with this _specific_ code snippet. On the other hand, the behavior is probably still software-related. Can you share additional code, how the flag is triggered by an EXTI? You wrote that the toggling stops completely, which hints at the EXTI ISR stopping to be executed.